# How to return image with bounding box using AWS Rekognition?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, opencv, amazon-rekognition, amazon-kinesis

When I upload image to s3 bucket and call AWS Rekognition detect_labels I am getting dictionary of detected labels like below

**{'Labels': [{'Name': 'Plant', 'Confidence': 99.70314025878906, 'Instances': [], 'Parents': []}, {'Name': 'Flower', 'Confidence': 98.37027740478516, 'Instances': [], 'Parents': [{'Name': 'Plant'}]}**

but here I need to return the image with bounding box where the object is identified, how this can be achieved ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `rekognition.detect_labels` method to perform object detection on the images. You can then use the `BoundingBox` property of `Labels` list to get the coordinates of the bounding box, the code below can be a good start.

```py
import boto3
import io
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

file_name = 'plant.jpg'
# Get Rekognition client
rek_client = boto3.client('rekognition')
with open(file_name, 'rb') as im:
    # Read image bytes
    im_bytes = im.read()
    # Upload image to AWS 
    response = rek_client.detect_labels(Image={'Bytes': im_bytes})
    # Get default font to draw texts
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(im_bytes))
    font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', size=80)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    # Get all labels
    w, h = image.size
    for label in response['Labels']:
        name = label['Name']
        # Draw all instancex box, if any
        for instance in label['Instances']:
            bbox = instance['BoundingBox']
            x0 = int(bbox['Left'] * w) 
            y0 = int(bbox['Top'] * h)
            x1 = x0 + int(bbox['Width'] * w)
            y1 = y0 + int(bbox['Height'] * h)
            draw.rectangle([x0, y0, x1, y1], outline=(255, 0, 0), width=10)
            draw.text((x0, y1), name, font=font, fill=(255, 0, 0))

    image.save('labels.jpg')
```

Answer (score 2):

From [DetectLabels API documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_DetectLabels.html):

> DetectLabels returns bounding boxes for instances of **common** object labels in an array of Instance objects. An Instance object contains a BoundingBox object, for the location of the label on the image. It also includes the confidence by which the bounding box was detected.

This is elaborated more in [Detecting labels documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/labels.html)

> Amazon Rekognition Image and Amazon Rekognition Video can return the
> bounding box for common object labels such as cars, furniture, apparel
> or pets. Bounding box information isn't returned for less common
> object labels. You can use bounding boxes to find the exact locations
> of objects in an image, count instances of detected objects, or to
> measure an object's size using bounding box dimensions.

In short, bounding box information isn't returned for all labels. @Allan Chua's code will draw bounding boxes in the image only if the label is a 'common object' which has bounding box information. In the sample API response you provided, none of the labels have bounding box information.